# How not to mix hash and keywordArgument in a Ruby function?

Tags: ruby, hash, keyword-argument

```
    def passingHash(it)
        p it
    end

    def passingKeywordArg(name: 'David', number: 15)
        p name
        p number
    end

    # We actually pass a hash here.
    passingHash(name: "hello", number: 100) # Print {:name=>"hello", :number=>100}

    # These are two arguments.
    passingKeywordArg(name: "hello", number: 100) # Print  "hello"  100
```

I'm learning Ruby now. I found these two invocations look the same, but their parameters are totally different. Is using => to represent the hash a recommended way here? I looked up into this [code style guideline](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#symbols-as-keys) and found => is not recommended to use. Did I misunderstand anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial is not saying that using `=>` (AKA "hash-rocket") is bad, it's saying the use of Strings or other objects besides symbols (`:foo`) uses more memory.

```
{ :foo => 'bar' }
```

is the original way of defining a symbol as a key. Compare these two definitions:

```
{ :foo => 'bar' } # => {:foo=>"bar"}
{ foo: 'bar' }    # => {:foo=>"bar"}
```

We tend to use `foo:` because we're [lazy](http://threevirtues.com).

Symbols don't cost as much, but that's a different subject and why can be found with a little searching.

As developers we need to understand the cost of using one algorithm or object versus another. Using Strings or whatever as a key has its time and place and knowing those can save a lot of memory or development time.

Finally, style guides are useful; Read several of them periodically and consider what they're suggesting. The guides are aimed at teams to help them write in a common and consistent manner following good coding practices adapted for Ruby, however they're not cast in stone. Knowing why they're recommended is important, because occasionally we have to ignore or bend the rules, but, when we do, we better be ready to explain why in a code-review.

And, if you're not familiar with Ruby's coding styles, I'd recommend learning about [Rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop), which is a nice tool for checking for consistent and accepted programming style and catching errors.

Comment: thank you. That being said, does it recommend to use the hash rocket under the situation I mentioned?

Comment: That guide says to not use `=>`, but that's being artificially strict on their part if you're using a symbol for the key already. Ruby doesn't care, and it'll create the same object in memory so as far as I see it it's a moot point. Do what fits your head. I was tech-lead for years, and if someone whined about that small point in a code-review I'd have told them to think about whether other issues were more important.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I totally agree with you and will look into the materials you provide.

Comment: The `{ foo: "bar" }` syntax sugar was not available in older versions of Ruby. So you'll see older styles using the more verbose `{ :foo => "bar" }`. They do the same thing, but the former is now preferred.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to The Tin Man's answer, here's more specifics about passing keyword arguments.

Ruby has some [syntax sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) which translates hashes into keyword arguments, keyword arguments into hashes.

When you run `passingHash(name: "hello", number: 100)`, Ruby sees that `passingHash` takes a single positional argument and translates it into `passingHash({name: "hello", number: 100})` and you get a single Hash.

When you run `passingKeywordArg(name: "hello", number: 100)`, Ruby sees that `passingKeywordArg` takes keyword arguments and leaves it alone. You get individual keyword arguments.

You can also write `passingKeywordArg({name: "hello", number: 100})` which Ruby will translate into keyword arguments, but that will be [deprecated in 2.7 and removed in 3.0](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/10/07/ruby-2-7-keyword-arguments-redesign.html) for more.

`passingKeywordArg("name" => "hello", "number" => 100)` will not work. In this case you're passing in [Strings](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) as keys. Ruby will not turn strings into keywords. `passingKeywordArg(name: "hello", number: 100)` uses [Symbols](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html), not a [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) as keys, Ruby will translate symbols into keywords.

In conclusion: `{ "name" => "hello", "number" => 100 }` makes a Hash with String keys. `{ name: "hello", number: 100 }` makes a Hash with Symbol keys. Ruby will translate Symbols into keyword arguments, but not Strings.